# What does a picture of a blue person outline on a folder in windows 10 mean

Tags: windows-10

I have several folders with pictures of a person on them in windows 10. As far as I'm aware they aren't Google Drive or One Drive folders, so what does it mean? I added the `index_files` folder

It's an old machine so could be another program

[image: folders]

Large folders look like this:

[image: large folders]

Running **folder > Properties > Customize > Change Icon**, the image appears to be coming from:
[image: folder image selector]

Comment: Do you have File Sharing enabled?

Comment: aplogies, how would i find that out? It doesn't appear on some other folders, so was thinking it might be git related?

Comment: Can you add what it looks like in large icons view? To see if it's shared, right-click the folder > properties > sharing tab, and it probably says Not Shared. The shared folder icon is this one: https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/folder-users-permissions-share-icon.png

Comment: Try to right-click the folder > Properties > Customize > Change Icon, and check where windows is loading the icon from. The default for windows icons is shell32: `%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll`. This doesn't look like one of the built-ins, so the path is probably to a program files location, which should tell you what program changes the icon

Comment: @Cpt.Whale it's not shared and I updated the question to show the icon address, which seems to be the one you said was the default

Comment: It's likely not an icon – it's an overlay, so it won't show up in "Change Icon". Try NirSoft's ShExView instead.

Comment: @pluke - These folders clearly belong to a Git repository.  Are the folders in a Git repository? To determine if you are sharing a folder, determine if it's enabled on the machine itself, in this case it's immaterial.  You shoud do research to determine if File Sharing is enabled or disabled on your system though.

Comment: Ah, that's what i looking for. It's strange that even copying the folder from one location to another (non got) location retains the icon